# Select where not in another select

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Im trying to

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bus_user_perms` 
WHERE `Perm_id` NOT IN (SELECT `Perm_id` 
                        FROM `bus_user_perms` 
                        GROUP BY `Perm_username`, `Perm_BusArId`)
```

but its not returning anything and I think it should because when I run:

```
SELECT `Perm_id` 
FROM `bus_user_perms` 
GROUP BY `Perm_username`, `Perm_BusArId`
```

I get 870 results

and when I run

```
SELECT `Perm_id` 
FROM `bus_user_perms`
```

I get 931 results.

Essentially I'm trying to get the 61 results not in the 870

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you're 'trying to'. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to find duplicates based on username and busairid grouping. Try the below query to achieve the same.

```
SELECT `Perm_id` 
FROM `bus_user_perms` 
GROUP BY `Perm_username`, `Perm_BusArId`
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks! so obvious now that I see the answer *face palm*

Answer (score 0):

There must only be 870 distinct perm_id’s in the resultset that has 931. Try adding the DISTINCT keyword in.

Answer (score 0):

It will not return anything because all of your `Perm_id` from the external query will have an entry in the subquery

What is the structure of the table and what are you trying to query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Perm_id` 
FROM `bus_user_perms` 
GROUP BY `Perm_username`, `Perm_BusArId`
```

Returns all the `Perm_id`s with unique `Perm_username` and `Perm_BusArId`.

```
SELECT `Perm_id` 
FROM `bus_user_perms`
```

Returns all the `Perm_id`s in it.

It could happened that duplicated `Perm_id`s are allowed on this table. So running:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bus_user_perms` 
WHERE `Perm_id` NOT IN (SELECT `Perm_id` 
                        FROM `bus_user_perms` 
                        GROUP BY `Perm_username`, `Perm_BusArId`)
```

could return nothing. To get the duplicated data run:

```
SELECT `Perm_id` 
FROM `bus_user_perms` 
GROUP BY `Perm_username`, `Perm_BusArId`
HAVING count(*) > 1
```